# stack overflow when using copy constructor and/or assignment operator with string in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, stack-overflow, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

i'm trying to run insertion sort on a simple class of my own making, which features a couple fields (int, float, and string) as well as a copy constructor, assignment operator, and '>' operator.

however, i'm getting a stack overflow when i run the code below. visual studio tells me its coming from the getName() function in my 'Student' class. the error originates from the assignment in my insertion sort function `arr[i + 1] = arr[i];`

anyone know why this is? i'm relatively new to c++, coming from mostly a java background.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Student {
public:
    Student(string nm, int ID, float avg): name(nm), studentID(ID), overallAverage(avg) {}

    Student(const Student& rhs) : name(rhs.getName()), studentID(rhs.getStudentID()), overallAverage(rhs.getOverallAverage()) {}

    // copy and swap idiom
    Student& operator=(const Student& rhs) {
        Student copy = rhs;  // places a copy of rhs into copy using the copy constructor (copy will be cleaned up on return)
        swap(*this, copy); // move copy or rhs into this, this is a pointer to current object, *this dereferences the pointer
        return *this; 
    }
    ~Student() {}

    bool operator>(const Student& rhs) {
        if (rhs.getOverallAverage() > overallAverage)
            return false;
        else return true; 
    }

    string getName()const { return name; }
    int getStudentID()const { return studentID;  }
    float getOverallAverage()const { return overallAverage; }

private:
    string name; 
    int studentID; 
    float overallAverage; 

};

template<typename T> 
vector<T>& insertionSort(vector<T>& arr){
    for (int j = 1; j < arr.size(); j++) {
        T key = arr[j]; 
        int i = j - 1; 
        while (i > -1 && arr[i] > key) {
            arr[i + 1] = arr[i]; 
            i = i - 1; 
        }
        arr[i + 1] = key; 
    }
    return arr; 
}


int main()
{
    vector<Student> students = {Student("russ",0,89),Student("Seb",1,75),Student("julia",2,85),
                                Student("johnny",3,90),Student("Sushma",4,55)}; 

    students = insertionSort(students); 

    for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
        cout << students[i].getName() << ", ";
    }
    cout << endl;  
}
```

original operator= from txtbook i'm using:

```
IntCell & operator= ( const IntCell & rhs ) // Copy assignment
{
IntCell copy = rhs;
std::swap( *this, copy );
return *this;
}
```

Comment: Your `operator =` calls `std::swap`, which calls your `operator =`, which calls `std::swap`, which calls your `operator =`, which calls `std::swap` ...

Comment: really? i coped that operator= directly from a well-known c++ textbook :
edit-> put the textbook's operator= at bottom of my original question

Comment: In that book, did the class have its own `swap` function?  If so, that is what prevented the infinite recursion.  The `std::swap` will use the class `swap` function.

Comment: ah, i see you're right. upon re-reading that section it mentions:
"t. Notice that if swap were implemented using the basic copy algorithm in Figure
1.14, the copy-and-swap idiom would not work, because there would be mutual nonterminating recursion. In C++11 we have a basic expectation that swapping is implemented
either with three moves or by swapping member by member"

Comment: A generic routine like `std::swap` requires that the arguments be [Swappable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Swappable), and obviously your `Student` class was not, until a custom `Student::swap` function is created.

Comment: IMO it'd be better to use rule of zero here, unless this is just an exercise to learn about copy-and-swap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The infinite recursion is caused by `std::swap` calling `Student::operator=`, which calls `std::swap`, which calls `Student::operator=`, etc.

To alleviate this, write your own `swap` function that calls `std::swap` on each of the members:

```
class Student
{
//...
   void swap(Student& left, Student& right)
    {
        std::swap(left.name, right.name);
        std::swap(left.studentID, right.studentID);
        std::swap(left.overallAverage, right.overallAverage);
    }
//...
};
```

Comment: thanks. it works now. the std::swap didn't work (error - no instance of overloaded function std::swap matches the argument list)

so i just did left.name = right.name, etc. is this bad?

Comment: See what [std::swap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Swappable) expects the arguments to be.